# balance_updates section

Tags: node

i am getting the details of block- 24576 which is a reward block of cycle 0

"balance_updates": [
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3NExpXn9aPNZPorRE4SdjJ2RGrfbJgMAaV",
                "change": "-40000000"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                "category": "deposits",
                "delegate": "tz3NExpXn9aPNZPorRE4SdjJ2RGrfbJgMAaV",
                "level": 5,
                "change": "40000000"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                "category": "fees",
                "delegate": "tz3bvNMQ95vfAYtG8193ymshqjSvmxiCUuR5",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-1157138"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3bvNMQ95vfAYtG8193ymshqjSvmxiCUuR5",
                "change": "1157138"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                "category": "fees",
                "delegate": "tz3bTdwZinP8U1JmSweNzVKhmwafqWmFWRfk",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-1420068"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3bTdwZinP8U1JmSweNzVKhmwafqWmFWRfk",
                "change": "1420068"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                "category": "fees",
                "delegate": "tz3WMqdzXqRWXwyvj5Hp2H7QEepaUuS7vd9K",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-1250233"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3WMqdzXqRWXwyvj5Hp2H7QEepaUuS7vd9K",
                "change": "1250233"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                "category": "fees",
                "delegate": "tz3VEZ4k6a4Wx42iyev6i2aVAptTRLEAivNN",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-774255"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3VEZ4k6a4Wx42iyev6i2aVAptTRLEAivNN",
                "change": "774255"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                "category": "fees",
                "delegate": "tz3UoffC7FG7zfpmvmjUmUeAaHvzdcUvAj6r",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-1307180"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3UoffC7FG7zfpmvmjUmUeAaHvzdcUvAj6r",
                "change": "1307180"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                "category": "fees",
                "delegate": "tz3RDC3Jdn4j15J7bBHZd29EUee9gVB1CxD9",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-1623135"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3RDC3Jdn4j15J7bBHZd29EUee9gVB1CxD9",
                "change": "1623135"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                ***"category": "fees",***
                "delegate": "tz3RB4aoyjov4KEVRbuhvQ1CKJgBJMWhaeB8",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-1796254"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3RB4aoyjov4KEVRbuhvQ1CKJgBJMWhaeB8",
                "change": "1796254"
            },
            {
                "kind": "freezer",
                ***"category": "fees",***
                "delegate": "tz3NExpXn9aPNZPorRE4SdjJ2RGrfbJgMAaV",
                "level": 0,
                "change": "-1400039"
            },
            {
                "kind": "contract",
                "contract": "tz3NExpXn9aPNZPorRE4SdjJ2RGrfbJgMAaV",
                "change": "1400039"
            }
        ]
    },

There are multiple category fees section in the balance updates where level =0 is mentioned which confirms that these are the fees of the operations in Cycle 0 which are released in this Cycle - 5

if we sum up these fees will this be the total reward for the baker of this block ?

Answer (score 2):

The total reward for a baker of *any* block is 16xtz for the block + fees for operations in this block. At the end of a cycle, there are other "fees" from operations that happened earlier in this cycle like nonce revelation, or possibly double bake evidence, etc. All of those extraneous fees are summed up in 1 go in the last block of the cycle.

Comment: the query i asked and the answer are completely different . Let me rephrase my question

 

For cycle 0 we have 0-4095 blocks so as of my knowledge the rewards for Cycle 0 is distributed at the end block(24576) of cycle 5 - please validate if this is correct.

So the json provided above if of block 24756 please look into a part of that and as well level :0

{ "kind": "freezer", "category": "fees", "delegate": "tz3RB4aoyjov4KEVRbuhvQ1CKJgBJMWhaeB8", "level": 0, "change": "-1796254" },

Comment: Yes, block 24576 contains the rewards for cycle 0. You asked 1 specific question in your post, "if we sum up these fees will this be the total reward for the baker of this block?" I answered this question, the answer is no. The baker of block 24576 receives 16xtz + all other fees from the cycle.

Comment: Level 0 is the Genesis block. The genesis block has no baker and no rewards are given for this block.

Comment: I scanned the first 1024 blocks
`$ for i in {1..1024}; do curl -s http://node/chains/main/blocks/$i | jq '.metadata.balance_updates'; done`
and none contained any balance update rewards.
If I still did not answer your question, then I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Your first comment did not rephrase anything helpful to me in understanding your question.

Comment: that was really really helpful to me . Thanks a ton. Just one quick check the 16XTZ reward do we have a separate transaction for that some where

Comment: No. The baking block reward is included in the block's balance_update as freezer:rewards to the bakers address.

Comment: Thanks a ton, your comments were really helpful

Comment: @user3759202 please mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied